# How to add Default datetime for another field data insertion in Oracle?

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I used below query

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE NAME MODIFY FIELD1 DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE FOR FIELD2;
```

getting this error message : "ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option"

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this statement? Change the datatype of column field1 to date and change the default value of column field2 to sysdate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A short question, hence a short answer:

There's no such thing in Oracle SQL as `default some_value for another column`.

You can add a default value for a column.

Or you can add a virtual column providing some calculation (with some default values involved, too) based on multiple columns.